# How to set the autoresize property to change according to orientation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an application created with a root class to be UIViewController class. I have placed one button on its view with frame size fixed in the view and have also set:

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
        return YES;
}
```

Now when i rotate the button remains in the same place except it is turned up.
If i set the autoresizing will the UIButton appears in the proper position.
If so how to set the autoresizing??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start here with moving and resizing objects

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Layout/Layout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH19-SW1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am working on application without a .xib file where UI is designed programatically. Can u give the solution when i do it programatically?